# Where is the Webservice Queries(SQL) of Magento 2 on code level?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework2, magento2.1

i need to know where is the location of Webservice Queries of Magento2.
For example, when i call the url using POSTMAN:

```
https://yourwebsite/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria
```

I get All orders from all stores on my magento application.
So, Where this querie is made? what path? path module? How can i get this? Where SQL is made?

Answer (score 0):

Open up the file in path
`../vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/webapi.xml`
in the same there is a class assigned to handle the above mentioned rest-api i.e. Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
And the equivalent Resource Model available to fetch the order details is 
`<preference for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface" type="Magento\Sales\Model\Order"/>`
which is defined in the path "../vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/di.xml"
So whenever you hit the rest api it will be processed by ***Magento\Sales\Model\Order*** as it implements the OrderInterface which is accessed by the rest Api.